# Is the product of n iid random variables equal to one of those rv's to the power of n?

Tags: statistics

If I have $X_i$ for $i = 1,2,...,n$ that are iid, then is it true that their product $\prod{X_i}$ is just ${X_1}^n$?

And would $E[\prod{X_i}] = E[{X_1}^n]$?

Comment: Umm, no? If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent rolls of a fair six-sided die, and it happens that $X_1=3$ and $X_2=5$, then their product $3 \times 5$ is not just $3^2$.

Comment: $\prod X_i$ equals ${X_1}^n$ only if $n=1$ or $\mathbb P(X_1=c)=1$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$. This being said, $E[\prod X_i]=E[X_1]^n$ (not $E[{X_1}^n]$).

Comment: @nejimban I know what you were getting at, but the second condition of your first sentence is a bit wacky...  $X_1\cdot X_2 = cX_2$ a.s. if $X_1 =c$ a.s.

Comment: @peterag yes we agree it is a boring degenerate case :-)

Comment: @nejimban all I meant was that, using Jukka's example above, say, if $X_1 = 3 $ almost surely, and $X_2 =5$ a.s., then $X_1\cdot X_2 = 15$ a.s., and not $3^2$, as - I think -  your first sentence would otherwise suggest.

Comment: @peterag, oh, but then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not iid as OP initially stated.

Comment: Oops you're right. But I'll leave my (stupid) comments for the edification and amusement of others...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: no.

On the other hand,
$E [\prod X_i] = \prod E [X_i]$ if the $X_i$ are independent. If, furthermore, they are i.i.d., $E [X_1] = E[X_2]=\cdots = E[X_n]$, so
$$E[\prod X_i] = \prod E [X_i] = \Big(E[X_1]\Big)^n.$$